# How to store each field data in string from List?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp

I created a java class that fetch data from database and add to a list.and the methord dbd() return the List.

```
public class db {
  public List dbd() {
   List myList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:*********,*******");
            Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(" SELECT name_id,address,image from data where name="kiran";" )  ;
                 while(rs2.next())
                  {
                  myList.add(rs2.getString("name_id"));
                  myList.add(rs2.getString("address"));
                  myList.add(rs2.getString("image"));
                  }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        return myList;
             }

    public static void main(String args[]){ 

     }

}
```

in this jsp page i created object of db as nw. and by using  Iterator i can print all the field data from data base.

```
 <%
   db nw = new db();         
   Iterator it = nw.dbd().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
     out.println(it.next());
    }         

 %>
```

**** I NEED TO STORE EACH FIELD DATA TO STORE BACK TO INDIVIDUAL STRING LIKE name_id,address,image .. WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: And don't please shout on us. WE ARE NOT DEAF.

Comment: What's your question ? Which error you are facing ?

Comment: there is no error.. but this code print all data in the page.but i need to get individual field data and store in to strings  name_id,address,image and print separate.

Answer (score 1):

Java List provides an ordered collection. What you have done: you have added number of strings to your collection based on index order. I.e. each new String added to list will have the next index. This mean, if you have 3 columns in your database, you have added consecutively value of "name_id", "address" and "image". One solution could be:

```
            int ind = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String name;
        String address;
        String image;
        if (ind % 3 == 0)
            name = it.next();
        else if (ind % 3 == 1)
            address = it.next();
        else if (ind % 3 == 2)
            image = it.next();
                    ind++;
    }
```

Personnaly, I would preffer to store this data in ArrayList in the following way:

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    while(rs2.next()){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject().put("name_id", rs2.getString("name_id")).put("address", rs2.getString("address")).put("image", rs2.getString("image"));
    list.add(obj);
    }
```

In this case you will have grouped the row in the JSON object and you can retrieve the data like this:

```
    Iterator<JSONObject> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject obj = it.next();
        String name = obj.getString("name_id");
        String address = obj.getString("address");
        String image = obj.getString("image");
    }
```